# Unzip files with the same name from multiple directories

Tags: zip, file-search

I have the file `archive.zip` located in multiple directories, i.e.:

```
dir/001/archive.zip
dir/002/archive.zip
dir/003/archive.zip
...
```

Is there a way in which I can recursively unzip all the `archive.zip` files from all the directories with different names, using command line? The content of the ZIP files should be extracted to the same directory where the ZIP file resides.

The `dir` folder is common, only the parents of `archive.zip` have different names.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for `find`. Change to the directory `dir`, and issue the following command:

```
find . -type f -name "archive.zip" -execdir unzip {} \;
```

- This will search all directories starting with the current (`.`, which is equal to `dir` in your case) for files (`-type f`) with the name `archive.zip`.
- If found, it will execute the command `unzip {}` in the directory where the file was found (`-execdir`), with `{}` being the reference to the name of the found file (which `find` will replace with the actual filename - in this case, simply `archive.zip`).

It will have the same effect as saying `cd 001/; unzip archive.zip; cd ..; cd 002/; unzip archive.zip` ... (I think you get the point).

**Note** that the `;` terminating the command-to-be-executed must really be escaped with a `\`, otherwise the shell will interpret it before it reaches `find`.

Also, if the `dir/` directory itself can contain an `archive.zip` that you *don't want extracted*, you have to add the `-mindepth 1` argument after the starting point `.` to ensure that `find` only considers files starting at the first subdirectory-level below `dir/`.